# Problem with passing id via GET in Laravel

Tags: laravel, routes

Laravel framework 6.9 + XAMP

I need advise from someone with experience in Laravel as I have some strange issue I cannot explain.

Blade template has a button that should add an item to the cart via product id:

```
<div class="buy d-flex justify-content-between align-items-center">
     <div class="price text-success"><h5 class="mt-4">$ {{$product->price}}</h5></div>
     <a href="{{route('product.addToCart', ['id'=>$product->id] )}}" class="btn btn-danger mt-3"><i class="fas fa-shopping-cart"></i> Add to Cart</a>
</div>
```

However nothing happens when the button is clicked. No product id is passed, just #.

This is web.php route that I call:

```
    Route::get('add-to-cart/{id}', [
    'uses' => 'ProductController@getAddToCart',
    'as' => 'product.addToCart'
]);
```

Also tried:

```
//Route::get('add-to-cart/{id}', 'ProductController@getAddToCart')->name('product.addToCart');
```

Which also doesn't work.

This is Cart model:

```
<?php
namespace App;
class Cart
{
    public $items = null;
    public $totalQty = 0;
    public $totalPrice = 0;


    public function __construct($oldCart)
    {
        if ($oldCart) {
            $this->items = $oldCart->items;
            $this->totalQty = $oldCart->totalQty;
            $this->totalPrice = $oldCart->totalPrice;
        }
    }

    public function add($item, $id) {
        $storedItem = ['qty' => 0, 'price' => $item->price, 'item'=> $item];
        if ($this->items) {
            if (array_key_exists($id, $this->items)) {
                $storedItem = $this->items[$id];
            }
        }
        $storedItem['qty']++;
        $storedItem['price'] = $item->price * $storedItem['qty'];
        $this->items[$id] = $storedItem;


        $this->totalQty++;
        $this->totalPrice += $item->price;
    }
}
```

This is Product controller:

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Product;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Cart;
use Session;

class ProductController extends Controller
{

    public function index()
    {
        $products = Product::all();
        return view('shop.index', ['products' => $products]);
    }

    public function getAddToCart(Request $request, $id) {
        $product = Product::find($id);
        $oldCart = Session::has('cart') ? Session::get('cart') : null;

        $cart = new Cart($oldCart);
        $cart->add($product, $product->id);

        $request->session()->put('cart', $cart);
        //dd($request->session()->get('cart'));
        return redirect()->route('index');
    }
}
```

If I just pass in URL: /add-to-cart/{prod id} and Enter, it works - I get to see dd() of the 'cart' with the product details, so the route works. Only the button doesn't!

Drives me nuts. What am I doing wrong? Is there some 'feature' in Laravel I don't know about?

```
    dd($product)
App\Product {#279 ▼
  #fillable: array:3 [▼
    0 => "title"
    1 => "description"
    2 => "price"
  ]
  #connection: "mysql"
  #table: "products"
  #primaryKey: "id"
  #keyType: "int"
  +incrementing: true
  #with: []
  #withCount: []
  #perPage: 15
  +exists: true
  +wasRecentlyCreated: false
  #attributes: array:7 [▼
    "id" => 2
    "created_at" => "2019-12-22 18:05:40"
    "updated_at" => "2019-12-22 18:05:40"
    "imagePath" => "https://s3.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com/bootstrapbaymisc/blog/24_days_bootstrap/vans.png"
    "title" => "Neque quia sit facere."
    "description" => "Seven flung down his cheeks, he went on growing, and, as the door opened inwards, and Alice's elbow was pressed hard against it, that attempt proved a failure.  ▶"
    "price" => 29
  ]
  #original: array:7 [▶]
  #changes: []
  #casts: []
  #dates: []
  #dateFormat: null
  #appends: []
  #dispatchesEvents: []
  #observables: []
  #relations: []
  #touches: []
  +timestamps: true
  #hidden: []
  #visible: []
  #guarded: array:1 [▶]
}
```

The cart gets filled with product.

Comment: so what is the `href` that is being generated? Also you probably want to make this a POST action instead of GET.

Comment: what about the button doesn't work? what happens when you click it? what URL do you end up on? etc

Comment: have you tried this `{{route('product.addToCart', $product->id )}}` ?

Comment: Url in browser is empty. only # gets there. I also tried {{route('product.addToCart', $product->id )}} - nothing happens

Comment: Dump your product object to see if it's an actual object `@dd($product)`

Comment: it works, see above. perhaps something is not bootstrapped correctly. I am out of ideas.

Answer (score 0):

From what I'm seeing it seems that your route is not redirecting correctly. In your controller, the actions is defined as

`public function getAddToCart(Request $request, $id)`

but in your button you are only passing the `id` parameter.

Try redefining your method in your controller to

`public function getAddToCart($id)`

that should do the trick.

Comment: if i remove request from Product controller, nothing changes. Although I can dd() the contente of the 'cart', there is nothing added to the cart  via {{Session::has('cart') ?  Session::get('cart')->totalQty : ''}}

Comment: @PinPiguin have you tried doing dd on the session variable to verify that you have a cart in your session? I'm assuming from your comment that with the change you are routing correctly, is that so?

Comment: If I do: dd($request->session()->get($cart)); I get error array_key_exists(): The first argument should be either a string or an integer from Cart. There I pass $item  adn $id.    I do this by passing /add-to-cart/2 in url as the button does not work - it is never wired for some reason I get # when trying to click it :(

Comment: `session()->get('cart')`, the get method takes the "key" so you would previously do something like `$request->session()->put('cart', $cart);`. See https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/session#storing-data, might help.